Additional Moderator Needed
Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, I need to appoint another provisional Moderators to help moderate this site. 
Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selection. You can read more about the process here: Moderators Pro Tempore.
The Nomination Process:

Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
Self nominations are encouraged. This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the --- markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:
We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

Have been consistently active in the site's activities;
Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities;
Leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write;
Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

<h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>

<h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>

Notes:

<why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>

---

(this section is edited in by the nominee)
I accept/decline this nomination

I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am 
generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may 
want to know about me are…

etc.



I hope to see some proposals made by members of the community soon.

@Charo Thanks for all the nominations and the effort that you put into this site!

Denis Nardin
Meta Profile
Notes:

He's been an active user on this site for some years.
He has participated in Meta, showing interest in building this community.
He visits the site very frequently.
He leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything he writes.
He has completed several review tasks.
He is very interested in improving the quality of this site.
‎He's very active in another Stack Exchange site.


I accept this nomination
I am Denis Nardin, 30 years old. I work as a math postdoc (junior researcher). I live in France, so I am 
generally active on this site from 9:00 CET to 21:00 CET but having an irregular workload my presence might be a bit erratic.
Most of my experience in the Stackexchange network is on Mathoverflow, which is a little different from other sites, so I could be bringing a bit of that baggage with me (e.g. in being a stickler for having good references in answers).
I believe we should be very welcoming to newcomers but I have problems dealing with people that drop a question on our lap and then give no further feedback.
I thank you for having considered me for this position. If I'll serve as a moderator I'll do my best to help this site grow.

I'm a bit afraid about the time commitment. The time I'm free to spend on this website is very inconsistent and depends a lot on my current workload. Could you comment on that?

@DenisNardin: From my experience, it's not really so much time. And if sometimes you are really so busy that you can't even visit the site... well, I think this is the reason why it's a good idea to have three moderators.

Thank you very much for your answer (and also for the nomination, of course). I think I'll reflect on it for a couple of days.

@DenisNardin I confirm: the amount of intervention needed is small. Being three people would make the job even more relaxed.

@DenisNardin: I'm glad to read this!

@DenisNardin Congratulations! I'm sure you'll made a great job!

@DenisNardin Congrats, Denis! Well deserved.

Hey, @DenisNardin: d'you miss the email I sent you, given you're willing to take up the mantle? :) I never heard from you...

@JNat I never received it. This summer I changed the email address I use on SE because I changed job (yeah, in retrospective it was silly to use my work address while registering to Mathoverflow), maybe you sent it to the old one?

Ah! I emailed it to the email you have set as your primary contact option, @Denis — maybe updating that would be a good idea? ;P I'll send to the one associated with the most recently used credential on your account instead.

DaG
Meta Profile
Notes:

He's been a very active user since this site's creation.
He has participated in Meta, showing interest in building this community.
He visits the site very frequently.
He leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything he writes.
He has completed several review tasks.
He is very interested in improving the quality of this site.
‎He's active in other Stack Exchange sites.


DaG here. I sincerely appreciate the nomination and thank you all for it – and I am not saying this just because it has to be said – but I have to decline it again.

I'm aware of what you said last time. But, seeing what you are doing for the site,  I can assure you that you won't need to spend more time being a moderator here.

I agree with you, DaG would be great as a moderator

abarisone
Meta Profile
Notes:

He's been a very active user on this site for the last years.
He has participated in Meta, showing interest in building this community.
He visits the site very frequently.
He leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything he writes.
He has completed several review tasks.
He is interested in improving the quality of this site.
‎He's active in another Stack Exchange site.


Thanks a lot for considering me suitable for the position!!!

I'm also concerned about the amount of time required to guarantee a fair level of moderation by my side. It's a pity that DaG declined but I think also @DenisNardin could be great as well as a moderator.

@abarisone: I can assure you that it's no more time than the one you are already spending on the site.

Maybe next year...

@abarisone I don't particularly want to become a moderator, so if it is something you care a lot about doing, it probably should be you. I'm sure you would do an exemplary job.

I’m sorry you considered my comment as a complaint by my side. It’s correct that you become a moderator this year because you have been active on this site a long time before I do and you brought a lot of valuable content to this site. I’m sure you’ll be great as a moderator and I think I’ll try this experience next year. Don’t worry about that and enjoy this experience.

@abarisone I didn't take it as a complaint, I just don't think the fact that I received 2 votes more than you makes much of a difference between us :). I don't know how the decision is taken, though. Anyway, I believe both of us have the best interests italian.SE at heart.
